# How to use my custom Symfony 3.0 Library/Bundle/HowIsCalled

Tags: php, symfony

By looking these piece of documentation:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#basic-usage

I have made this Library:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ConfigurableExtension;

class Image extends ConfigurableExtension
{
    /*The size of the thumbnail*/
    private $thumb_max_width=100;
    private $thumb_max_height=100;
    /*End of: "The size of the thumbnail"*/

    private $image_width=0;
    private $image_height=0;

    /**
    *Contains the Image Data
    */
    private $image=null;

    protected function setThumbHeight($value)
    {
      $thumb_max_height=$value>0?$value:0;
    }

    protected function setThumbWidth($value)
    {
      $thumb_max_width=$value>0?$value:0;
    }

    /**
    *Function that Loads the configuration
    */
    protected function loadInternal(array $mergedConfig, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        var_dump($mergedConfig);
    }

    /**
    *Loads a $file from $extention
    *@param $file {String} The path of file
    *@param $extention {String} the type or the extention of the image
    *
    *@return This Object Instance
    */
    public function load($file)
    {

      $extention= exif_imagetype($file);

      switch($extention)
      {
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
          $this->image=imagecreatefrompng($file);
          break;

        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
          $this->image=imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
          break;

        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
          $this->image=imagecreatefromgif($file);
          break;
      }

      $this->image_width=imagesx($this->image);
      $this->image_height=imagesy($this->image);
      return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Resizes an Image
    * @param $width {Int} The new images width
    * @param $height {Int} The new Images Height
    *
    * @return The Object Instance
    */
    public function resize($width,$height)
    {
      $new_image=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image,$this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0,$width,$height);

      /*Set the new data to the Image*/
      imagedestroy($this->image);
      $this->image=$new_image;
      /*End of: "Set the new data to the Image"*/

      return $this;
    }

    /**
    *Generates a thumbnail of the image
    *The thumbnail size is retrieved from configuration
    *
    * @return The Object Instance
    */
    public function to_thumb()
    {
      $width=0;
      $width=0;

      /*Determine the resize width and height*/
      $source_aspect_ratio = $this->image_width / $this->image_height;
      $thumbnail_aspect_ratio = $this->thumb_max_width / $this->thumb_max_height;

      if ($this->image_width <= $this->thumb_max_width && $this->image_height <= $this->thumb_max_height)
      {
        $width = $this->image_width;
        $height = $this->image_height;
      }
      elseif ($thumbnail_aspect_ratio > $source_aspect_ratio)
      {
        $width = (int) ($this->thumb_max_height * $source_aspect_ratio);
        $height = $this->thumb_max_height;
      }
      else
      {
        $width = $this->thumb_max_width;
        $height = (int) ($this->thumb_max_width / $source_aspect_ratio);
      }
      /*End of: "Determine the resize width and height"*/

      $this->resize($width,$width);

      return $this;
    }

    /**
    *Exports the image to a file
    *@param file {String} The file path
    */
    public function export($file)
    {
      $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $ext=strtolower($ext);

      $write=false;

      switch($ext)
      {
        case 'png':
          imagesavealpha($this->image,true);
          $write=imagepng($this->image,$file);
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
          $write=imagejpeg($this->image,$file);
        case 'gif':
          $write=imagegif($this->image,$file);
      }
      imagedestroy($this->image);
    }
}
?>
```

The library above is located in *src/AppBundle/ImageBundle/DependencyInjection/Image.php*. And I want to be able to load it either in an Entity (on a Doctrine hook) or in a Controller. But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Also keep in mind if you coming from a `codeigniter` usage that the model implementation varies a LOT in Symfony.  The `Model` actually are the Services and there's no monolithic approach at all, so anything you need you pass it as an argument to the Service's Constructor so you need to design your application in an approach that the "Model" actually does one thing. So you need a "Model" for the Db I/O (aka `Doctrine` & `Repository`), a "Model" for Image manipulation and (optionally) a "Model" to put them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making too complicated stuff.

First, you cannot have a bundle inside a bundle (you said `src/AppBundle/ImageBundle`).

Then, your Library doesn't need to extend `ConfigurableExtension`.
So, after create a clean standalone bundle (`php app/console generate:bundle`),
create a `Util` directory into, move the class into and change it like :

```
namespace ImageBundle\Util;

class Image
{
    // Methods
}
```

Then, you can declare it as a service :

```
# app/config/services.yml
acme_image:
    class: ImageBundle\Util\Image
```

In a controller, use it like this :

```
$image = $this->get('acme_image');
```

In an entity (can't access the service container), just create a new instance of your class :

```
$image = new ImageBundle\Util\Image();
```

Note that Symfony is primarily a PHP framework.
Of course, there is very cool features and some complicated things at the first try, but it stays PHP.

**EDIT**

To use the `arguments` injected from the class of your service, just retrieve and define them in your constructor.

For example, inject the doctrine `EntityManager`:

```
# app/config/services.yml
acme_image:
    class: ImageBundle\Util\Image
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

Then, retrieve it from your class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
// ...

class Image
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
         $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    // ...

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // Use the defined property
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository(...);

        // ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: When I generate a new instanc of the ImageBundle\Util\Image how can I access the settings provides by services.yml?

Comment: You can inject what you want in your service by using `arguments` (another service, a defined parameter, ...) and retrieve them in the constructor of your class. Look at services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#service-parameters

Comment: I generated the Bundle but is has an ImageBundle.php file and the folders Controllers, Resouces and Tests Do I nees the following files?

Comment: It's the minimal structure of a bundle. `Resources/` will contains a `config` directory that should contains routes and services definition, a `public` directory for the assets of your bundle. `Controllers/` will contains all controllers of your bundle and the directory will be used to retrieve them, especially by the `RouterLoader` that will try to match them from your route definitions (e.g. `_controller: AppBundle:Default:index` will looks for a `AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction`). Finally, `Tests` is the testing directory of your bundle. So yes, you need these files.

Comment: But if no parameters provided on the constructor (making thw instance inside the ) how can I retrieve them from the services.yml I mean By calling the new ImageBundle\Util\Image() hoc can I read the values from services.yml?

Comment: I added an example to show you how to use the injected arguments from your service's class.

Comment: You don't have to call new Image(), just $this->container->get('acme_image');